# CSS to only target if there are 2 or more elements

Tags: html, css

I'd like to give a table `width 100%` and if there are 2 inside the element `50%`;

So far I have

```
    table { 
        width: 100%;
    }
    table + table {
        width: 50%;
    }
    //Outputs
    table + table { //rules only apply to the second table
```

This means if there are two tables the second gets its own styles, but I need both tables to now be 50%. No Js either please. Thats easy

Comment: That's not CSS. If you tagged [tag:css], please post formatted CSS output only. Not preprocessor syntax.

Comment: Consider using a flexbox layout - although you may need `<div>`s wrapping your tables to prevent things breaking.

Comment: Interesting idea for sure, not sure its quite what i need for the entire site though

Comment: Yes I do, but since CSS is a mark up language, how would `table + table` even do anything in CSS?

Comment: What you should rather do is give both tables a class in your html by doing `class='table2'` and then in your css you would use `.table2{ width: 50%;}` where the `.` would stand for `class` or a `#` would stand for an `ID`

Comment: I'm not being rude, im just saying your syntax is incorrect.. but fine, i'm outta here.

Comment: @Azrael Please think before you A) vote down B) Talk :) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

Comment: I did not vote down.. What's wrong with you man.

Comment: Then vote up lol ;) Because I just tought you something

Comment: sigh, you gotta be kidding me man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to accomplish something like this is a bit counterintuitive and I might be forgetting some edge cases, but this should work:

```
table {
   width: 50%;
}
table:last-child:first-child {
   width: 100%;
}
```

But this only works inside a wrapper where the only children are your tables. This way we only make it `100%` wide if its the only child, otherwise default to `50%`.

Comment: Arghh brilliant, why hadn't I thought of first-child!!! kiss u

Comment: Ha cheers. I was typing a comment about it not being possible when I thought of this one :)